# Kafka consumer not displaying the message

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I am trying to understand how a Kafka producer works. Below is the python producer code I wrote to send a message. I started the Kafka console consumer first and then I am running the python code

```
from confluent_kafka import Producer
from Product import Product
from faker import Faker



if __name__ == '__main__':


    config = {
        "bootstrap.servers":"localhost:9092"
    }
    producer = Producer(config)
    fake = Faker()
    product = Product(fake.name())
    print(product.serial())
    producer.produce(topic="first_topic",value=product.serial())
```

The issue that I facing is that if I call flush method after calling produce the message appears on the console consumer however without flush the message doesn't appear in the console consumer. As per Kafka documentation flush will make the producer synchronous. Is there a way to avoid using the flush and still make sure the message gets consumed. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You either need to flush, or you need to fill the batch size of the producer via more messages or reduce the batch size below a single one of your messages via some librdkafka configuration setting within the confluent_kafka package

Answer (score 0):

You can either fill the batch size as @OneCricteer suggested or you can set the linger.ms to 0. So that it will not wait to fill up-to the batch size before send.